# Why am I losing my objects in NSMutableArray in function prepareForSegue? Crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a data object which I desire to store, access and modify at will between all the different views on my iOS application. The basic design premise is illustrated below. What is intriguing to me, is that if I replace NSMutableArray with NSString, it all works, no big deal, but the moment I make it an array and store a string within it, it freaks out. I opted for an array because I need to store different versions of userData at the same time and in the actual app, there is a lot more than just one user data variable.

I'm using ARC, but I have to admit I'm not clear on if I'm using it properly. Advice appreciated.

```
//  data.h

@interface Data : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *data;
@property (assign) NSNumber *Num; // determines which "level" on the array we're accessing

+(id) sharedInstance;

@end



// data.m

+(id) sharedInstance
{    
    static id sharedInstance = nil;
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];        
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {        
        _Num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        _data = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    return self;
}

// userInput.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userData;

@property (nonatomic, retain) Data *dataStore;
```

Here, I add an empty string to my data object, because none of the user input is mandatory, but when there is no input I need to know that, so at a minimum I use an empty string.

```
// userInput.m

viewDidLoad
{
    _dataStore = [Data sharedInstance];
            [_dataStore.data addObject:@""];

}

prepareForSegue
{
    int num = [_dataStore.Num intValue];

    NSString *transferData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _userData.text];
    [_dataStore.data replaceObjectAtIndex:num withObject:transferData]; // crash at this line. replacing the empty string with whatever the user inputs
}
```

Crash report

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Comment: why are you reinventing `NSArray`?

Comment: Is this related to your other question? I looked at your code there, and your were calling removeAllObjects on your arrays before you tried to call replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:. Are you doing the same thing here?

Comment: I agree with rdelmar, that the problem rests elsewhere. In answer to your question regarding ARC best practices, though, I'd suggest using `strong` rather than `retain` and `weak` instead of `assign`. Also, why would you want `Num` to be `assign`/`weak`? If you want your `Data` object to keep it, you probably want that to be `strong`.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, it's the same question, really. Since my last attempt was poor and rightfully down-voted I resubmitted this one.

removeAllObjects was only called in the last bit of code when the user pushes the "cancel" button. Or at least I think so.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the ARC advice!

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I need to be able to modify the array depending on what the user does. The user could have 1 to the n number of "layers" of data, thus, NSMutableArray.

Comment: No, it's called from the didMoveToParentViewController: method in Initial controller, which happens as soon as you click on "add new log" in the first screen that appears. So, this is before prepareForSegue is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your controller progression is like this:

ViewController ---> Initial ---> TDC

You get the shared instance of the FlightData class in the viewDidLoad method of ViewController, and the init code in that class instantiates all your arrays. Then, when you do prepareForSegue to go to Initial, you add the empty strings to those arrays. It's in the next controller, Initial, where the problem is. You call removeAllObjects on those arrays in didMoveToParentViewController which occurs right after the view appears. Then in prepareForSegue to go to TDC, you try to use replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: which of course crashes the app, since you just emptied those arrays.

Comment: Interesting. I know this is not part of the original question, but how can I detect when a view is "going back" to it's parent view? I need to be able to detect that on that view since it means that the User is "cancelling" and wants to set all values to NIL.

Comment: Which view are you talking about? I think in general, you probably want to use a delegate method, which you can fire off from the cancel button to send whatever you need to back to the previous controller. The other way would be to use an unwind segue (if you're using your own button, not the default back button).

Comment: Initial -> ViewController

I'm using the default back button. I'll investigate the docs a bit more.

Comment: I've just now implemented it to test first hand. Works great. Thanks again!